How to fill between stroke layers, without over filling previous strokes in Grease Pencil
Hi Blender community,
I am having major issues filling in between strokes in grease pencil and I have a deadline for school on Tuesday. I uploaded a video, and as you can see, I have the strokes on one layer, and I made sure that there are no gaps, and the strokes are clean and solid. In the video, I fill in the small areas with no problem and it works fine, but I am looking to fill the larger area around the small area, and whenever I do, it fills over the strokes in the small area. I am filling on the fill layer, and I don't understand why it will fill inside the small areas, but when I get to fill the large area, it doesn't pay attention to the strokes on the inside.
Help anyone, I need assistance, please.
Thanks.
Here is the link to the video.
https://go.screenpal.com/watch/cZf6DOVs4zr

Hello, please provide screenshots/your actual file.

You'll need to edit your original post and add the photos there. :)

Ok thank you, I added photos

The photos start at the bottom, the strokes with no fill. I add a fill to the small area, and it fills into the small circles. If I fill inside the circle, it will only fill the circle. Which is what I intend to do. It doesn't make sense that when I click the area outside of the circle, it also fills inside the circle.  That is the same issue when I click outside of that area, on the larger shape, and that also fills inside the same small area, the circles and the oval shape above. I just want the fill to stay inside the strokes.

@michael escobar, I don't suggest you use BSE (Blender Stack Exchange) to solve schoolwork projects because BSE is not Chegg.com. Most of us who answer questions do so during our spare time, so you won't get immediate answers when you are in a rush.

since you are on a time constraint, I suggest looking into grease pencil masking with your layers. It may lead to an appropriate solution for you.
